# Python (Django) sometimes ImportError

Tags: python, django, import

I've got a Django site that has been up and running for a while, but recently I started seeing an ImportError coming from some old code.  What's worse is that it seems almost random as to when it happens.

When it does happen, I hit the Django debug page, and it gives me 'ImportError: cannot import name schedule_utils'.  Generally, a page refresh or two will get it working properly - a server restart if that doesn't work.

Sorry if this question is a little vague, but I don't really understand the behavior much better than what I've described.  Has anyone else ran into this and can explain why it sometimes can't import something it clearly can?

EDIT: I've seen this running my dev branch, I haven't seen it in production and haven't heard any reports of it happening in production.  Here's the stack trace.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 91, in get_response
  request.path_info)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 216, in resolve
  sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 214, in resolve
  for pattern in self.url_patterns:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 243, in _get_url_patterns
  patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 238, in _get_urlconf_module
  self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
  __import__(name)

File "/home/django/app/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
  from integration import sync

File "/home/django/app/integration.py", line 18, in <module>
  from app.tasks.sync import do_sync

File "/home/django/app/tasks/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  import reports

File "/home/django/app/tasks/reports.py", line 14, in <module>
  from app.tasks import schedule_utils

ImportError: cannot import name schedule_utils
```

Comment: For starters, could you show the complete stack trace you are getting on the debug page?

Comment: How are you running your app (runserver, modwsgi, unicorn, etc.)? My first thought is that one of the processes serving up your app is running old code.

Comment: Just through runserver.  Production goes through Apache2, but like I said I haven't seen it in prod.  Could it just be because I'm running an old version of Django (1.2)?